# Android -- Include both text and html sharing services in chooser?

Tags: android, html, email, share

I want to share dynamic text fields for Facebook, Twitter, email and SMS apps.  For email, I want to include hyperlinks, so I'd need to use `"text/html"` instead of `"text/plain"`.  Is this impossible? The following code does not work:

```
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

    PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();

    List<ResolveInfo> activityList = pm.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, 0);
    for(final ResolveInfo app : activityList) {

        String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        targetedShareIntent.setType("text/plain");
        targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getTextToShare(data));
        targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);

    }

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("text/html");
    List<ResolveInfo> emailList = pm.queryIntentActivities(emailIntent, 0);
    for(final ResolveInfo app : emailList) {

        String packageName = app.activityInfo.packageName;
        Intent targetedShareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        targetedShareIntent.setType("text/html");

        if (packageName.contains("android.email") || packageName.contains("android.gm")) {
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, data.getHeadline());
            targetedShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(getTextToShare(data, "Email")));
        }

        targetedShareIntent.setPackage(packageName);
        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
    }

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(targetedShareIntents.size() - 1), "Share this story");
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

**EDIT**: This does work for Facebook, email -- however, for some reason Twitter does NOT show up. Does anyone know why?